# Magento sort order

Tags: php, magento

I am currently displaying items from a selected category in a slider in the following way:

```
    $cat_id = $homepage["homeproductstype_{$homepage['amount']}_3"];
    $_products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image', 'short_description'), 'inner')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('special_price')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
    ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id));
```

What I would like to do here though, is to have them displayed by ID in ASC order.

What is the best way to have this achieved?

Comment: I think by default it is ordered by id , but if it is not than you can try something like this  ->setOrder('id', "asc") at the end of query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `addAttributeToSort()` function to sort your collection based on id.

Add this to your collection `addAttributeToSort(’entity_id’, ‘asc’);`

See magento collection page for more info http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento

Comment: Thank you very much, I just figured this method out.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it out by adding

```
    ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'asc');
```